# Anyone know of any open access satellite/aerial imagery that doesnt need a transformation for use in UK in ArcMAP?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images, openstreetmap, remote-sensing

I'd like some satellite imagery (high res a possible but not essential) for use in ArcMAP (10.7) without a transformation.

I have high res (to cm scale) survey data to work with, the basic imagery basemap is not accurate with a transformaiton to OSGB36.